# Recursively Read from a .txt file Java

Tags: java, file, recursion

I created this method, but it only returns the first word in my txt file. I need the method to recursively go through my entire text file and return any words with the passed parameter 'theC' and ignore the words without 'theC'
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
public static String getWordsString(Scanner theFile, char theC)
{
  String words = "";

  if(theFile.hasNext())
  {
     String word = theFile.next();
     if(word.indexOf(theC) != -1)
     {
        words += word;
     }
     getWordsString(theFile, theC);
  }
  return words;
}
```

Example: System.out.println(getWordsString(scanner, 'c'));

would return any words in the txt file with the character c

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion here? A simple loop makes more sense.

Comment: 1st why recursion ?

2nd isn't this more logical `return words+ getWordsString(theFile, theC);` ??

Comment: Well, you're ignoring the returned `words` of the recursive calls. What do you expect?

Comment: @Abdelrahman Elkady 2nd actually looks like a solution, hence more logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just throwing the value of **`words`** away !

This should preserve the value and concatenate it with the next value

```
return words + getWordsString(theFile, theC);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the perfect answer. I'm just learning recursion so I didn't quite understand what I was doing.

Comment: It's not the perfect answer , It's just an answer and I hope it helps you :D

If yes then please mark it as the correct answer , Thanks